# Como exibir todas imagens de uma pasta no html?

Tags: php, html

Eu gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer para listar todas imagens de uma pasta no meu html.

Quero fazer com que minha página pegue todas as imagens da minha pasta e preencha minha galeria.

por exemplo,tenho esse grid:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>galeria de imagens</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="bulma" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.3.2/css/bulma.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container section">
    <div class="container is-12">
    </div>
    <div class="columns">

      <div class="column is-4">
        <div class="card">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column is-4">
        <div class="card">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column is-4">
        <div class="card">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Quero apenas criar a div uma unica vez e de forma ""automática"" preenche o restante obedecendo essa estrutura de três imagens por linha.
Assim sempre que eu jogar uma nova foto na pasta elá deverá aparecer nesta página.

Pesquisei e vi que isso só seria possível com php, estou estudando js e não entendo muito de php.

Comment: Por aqui sempre é um bom começo: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/getting-started.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar a leitura e impressão de todas as imagens de uma pasta você pode utilizar o seguinte codigo php para geração da sua listagem.

```
<?php

$pasta = ___DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."images"; 

$arquivos = glob("$pasta{*.jpg,*.jpg,*.JPG,*.png,*.gif,}", GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($arquivos as $id => $img){
   echo '<div class="column is-4">
    <div class="card"> '. $img . '</div>
  </div>';
}
?>
```